# Swing Undo Option

Tags: java, swing, undo

I have been watching tutorials on undo/redo option
for Java Swing GUI.  I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.  The following code is an inner class within another class.  The submit button works fine.  The undo option is not undoing when clicked.  Can someone let me know what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

```
private class listen implements ActionListener
{
    UndoManager manager;
    Document doc;
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) 
    {
        int result;
        Calendar times = Calendar.getInstance();
        createFile file = new createFile();
        manager = new UndoManager();
        doc = area.getDocument();
        String output_1, output_2, output_3, fileName;
        search find = new search();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JTextField input_1 = new JTextField(15);
        JTextField input_2 = new JTextField(15);
        JTextField input_3 = new JTextField(15);
        JLabel word_1 = new JLabel("KeyWord:");
        JLabel word_2 = new JLabel("KeyWord:");
        JLabel word_3 = new JLabel("KeyWord:");
        panel.add(word_1);
        panel.add(input_1);
        panel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(20));
        panel.add(word_2);
        panel.add(input_2);
        panel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(20));
        panel.add(word_3);
        panel.add(input_3);

        if(e.getSource() == submit)
        {
            do
            {
                result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, panel,
                        "KeyWords", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
                output_1 = input_1.getText();
                output_2 = input_2.getText();
                output_3 = input_3.getText();
                if( result == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION
                        && !find.isValidWord(output_1, output_2, output_3) )
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "<html>You must "
                            + "enter atleast 1 KeyWord, and also all<br> "
                            + "valid KeyWords must contain atleast one "
                            + "alphabetic letter,</html>");
                }
            }
            while(result == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION && 
                    !find.isValidWord(output_1, output_2, output_3));
            if(result == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION)
            {
                fileName = times.get(Calendar.MONTH) + "_" + 
                        times.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH + 1) + "_" + 
                        times.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "_" + output_1 + "_" +
                        output_2 + "_" + output_3 + "_";
                file.file(fileName, area.getText());
            }             
        }
        else if(e.getSource() == undo)
        {
            doc.addUndoableEditListener( new UndoableEditListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void undoableEditHappened( UndoableEditEvent e1 )
                {
                    manager.addEdit(e1.getEdit());
                    update();
                }
            });
            try
            {
                if( manager.canUndo() )
                    manager.undo();
            } catch(CannotUndoException exp) {}
        }
    }
    public void update()
    {
        undo.setEnabled(manager.canUndo());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have been watching tutorials -

Instead of watching tutorials, start with working code you can download from the Swing tutorial on [Implementing Undo/Redo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#undo).

I would guess you need to add the UndoableEditListener to the Document when you create the text component, NOT in the ActionListener. Otherwise, the edits are not being generated as text is added/removed.

Comment: Hey thx for the tip, you were right, I had to declare undomanager and document in the parent class and then add the undoableeditlistener,finally got it working! ,  it wont let me upvote this cuz im too new,